# Using MD5 hash value on an ansi string in Swift 3

Tags: swift, hash, md5

I have a small function that takes a string and returns its MD5 hash value. The problem is, that it expects a UTF8 string, and I need it to calculate a hash value of a byte array encoded with iso-8859-1 (~ansi).

How can I change the following code to accept a byte array of characters, then return its hashed value?

```
static func md5(_ string: String) -> String {
    let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_MD5_CTX>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    var digest = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CC_MD5_Init(context)
    CC_MD5_Update(context, string, CC_LONG(string.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)))
    CC_MD5_Final(&digest, context)
    context.deallocate(capacity: 1)
    var hexString = ""
    for byte in digest {
        hexString += String(format:"%02x", byte)
    }

    return hexString
}
```

The tricky part is the CC_MD5_Update call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily modify your function to take an arbitrary byte
array as argument. `CC_MD5_Update` is mapped to Swift as

```
func CC_MD5_Update(_ c: UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_MD5_CTX>!, _ data: UnsafeRawPointer!, _ len: CC_LONG) -> Int32
```

and you can pass an array as the `UnsafeRawPointer` parameter:

```
func md5(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    var context = CC_MD5_CTX()
    var digest = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CC_MD5_Init(&context)
    CC_MD5_Update(&context, bytes, CC_LONG(bytes.count))
    CC_MD5_Final(&digest, &context)
    return digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
}
```

(I have also simplified it a bit.)

Alternatively, pass a `Data` argument:

```
func md5(data: Data) -> String {
    var context = CC_MD5_CTX()
    var digest = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CC_MD5_Init(&context)
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_MD5_Update(&context, $0, CC_LONG(data.count))
    }
    CC_MD5_Final(&digest, &context)
    return digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
}
```

which can then be used as

```
let s = "foo"
if let data = s.data(using: .isoLatin1) {
    let hash = md5(data: data)
    print(hash)
}
```

---

**Update** for **Swift 5:**

```
import CommonCrypto

func md5(data: Data) -> String {
    var context = CC_MD5_CTX()
    var digest = Array<UInt8>(repeating:0, count:Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CC_MD5_Init(&context)
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_MD5_Update(&context, $0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count))
    }
    CC_MD5_Final(&digest, &context)
    return digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I decided to use the "data" approach. I appreciate your help, Martin.

Comment: Besides that, the digest.map { ... }.joined() is a nice one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your 'string' contains only utf8 characters, call CC_MD5_Update with string.utf8 so:

```
CC_MD5_Update(context, string.utf8, CC_LONG(string.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)))
```

Strings in swift are 'interesting', this is a good read on the topic: https://oleb.net/blog/2016/08/swift-3-strings/

Answer (score 0):

```
// requires a bridging header with this:
// #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
func MD5(_ string: String) -> String? {
    let length = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
    if let d = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        d.withUnsafeBytes { (body: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
            CC_MD5(body, CC_LONG(d.count), &digest)
        }
    }
    return (0..<length).reduce("") {
        $0 + String(format: "%02x", digest[$1])
    }
}
```

Justin Answer : https://gist.github.com/jstn/787da74ab4be9d4cf3cb